# How to enter NULL and Date values into table?

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I transfer the data into Tera Data with fastload now in one column 'ENDDATE' There are 2 values stored 'NULL' and Timestamp value like format

YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI:SS

I want to transfer both values into new table 
I want to NULL value replace with something and other Timestamp data to date format like

YYYY-MM-DD

How to transfer both values into table?

Comment: If the `'NULL'` is actually a `NULL` and not a string: `COALESCE(tscol, date '9999-12-31')`. Timestamp to Date : `CAST(tscol AS DATE)`

Comment: NULL Value is a character in the column written in 'NULL'

Comment: Then it's just `case when tscol = 'NULL' then <some date> else cast(tscol as date) end`.

Comment: Andrew  Error: Datatype Mismatch THEN/ELSE expression

Comment: What's your actual case statement?  Try casting the <some date> bit as  a date as well.

Comment: Make sure your `Then` and `Else` return the same data type: `case when tscol = 'NULL' then DATE <some date> else cast(tscol as date) end` OR `case when tscol = 'NULL' then CAST(<some date> as date) else cast(tscol as date) end`